# Dynamic var and Thread/sleep

Tags: multithreading, clojure, dynamic-variables

From what I read somewhere, if you bind a new value to a dynamic var in Clojure, that new value is only available in that thread.

So, in order to test that, I created this code:

```
(def *dynamic-var* "dynamic var")

(defn run-it [] 
  (future (binding [*dynamic-var* "new-value"] (Thread/sleep 3000) (println *dynamic-var*)))
  (future (Thread/sleep 1000) (println *dynamic-var*)))
```

My question is: why does the first thread (which must print "new-value") never run? It never prints "new-value" to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you need to mark your var as dynamic with metadata:

```
(def ^:dynamic *dynamic-var* "dynamic var")

(defn run-it [] 
  (future (binding [*dynamic-var* "new-value"] (Thread/sleep 3000) (println *dynamic-var*)))
  (future (Thread/sleep 1000) (println *dynamic-var*)))
```

With `^:dynamic` added, when you run `(run-it)` it will print out:

```
dynamic var
new-value
```

Without it you probably saw a warning printed:

> Warning: *dynamic-var* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *dynamic-var* or change the name.

Comment: Thank you, got it! I am making transition from static typed Java to dynamic typed Clojure. I am used to the support of IDE and making so many mistakes like this one because the tool just doesn't warn me. The "warning" you mentioned actually didn't show up anyway. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I got the warning when I was running the code in REPL, I didn't check if it is printed when it's run outside of REPL.